# How to solve the Session lock/performance problem of Codeigniter 4 when session_write_close() does not work?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm having an serious issue in my project (Codeigniter 4).

Suddenly, it started to show some strong peaks and the PHP process are locked for some seconds or minutes (even with a small number of users logged in).

The closest of a solution I've found  it was to apply
`session_write_close();` after anywhere I call session (there are some heavy AJAX).

This is what my server says it is taking time:

```
script_filename = //home/treineipassei/www/index.php
[0x00007f8480616d10] flock() /home/treineipassei/ci4/system/Session/Handlers/FileHandler.php:135
[0x00007f84806168a0] read() /home/treineipassei/ci4/system/Session/Session.php:894
[0x00007f8480616850] session_start() /home/treineipassei/ci4/system/Session/Session.php:894
[0x00007f84806167b0] startSession() /home/treineipassei/ci4/system/Session/Session.php:238
[0x00007f84806162a0] start() /home/treineipassei/ci4/system/Config/Services.php:577
[0x00007f8480616060] session() /home/treineipassei/ci4/system/Config/BaseService.php:189
[0x00007f8480615ef0] getSharedInstance() /home/treineipassei/ci4/system/Config/Services.php:563
[0x00007f8480615cd0] session() /home/treineipassei/ci4/app/Controllers/Pessoa.php:9
[0x00007f8480615bd0] __construct() /home/treineipassei/ci4/system/CodeIgniter.php:802
[0x00007f8480615ac0] createController() /home/treineipassei/ci4/system/CodeIgniter.php:403
[0x00007f84806154f0] handleRequest() /home/treineipassei/ci4/system/CodeIgniter.php:320
[0x00007f8480615230] run() /home/treineipassei/www/index.php:47
```

Comment: using `session_write_close();` is exactly what the docs say: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session_write_close#a-note-about-concurrency

Comment: I used  session_write_close(); after every call. 
 But still I do have issues. 
It could be a server config?

Comment: I just found this: 
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-write-close.php#120452

I will try to close  output_buffering and see what happens.

Comment: In case you find a nice solution, don't be shy to write a self-answer

Comment: Have you tried using a database for your session storage instead? Something to consider.